# How to set custom Jackson ObjectMapper with Spring Cloud Netflix Feign

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, feign, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm running into a scenario where I need to define a one-off @FeignClient for a third party API. In this client I'd like to use a custom Jackson ObjectMapper that differs from my @Primary one. I know it is possible to override spring's feign configuration defaults however it is not clear to me how to simply override the ObjectMapper just by this specific client.

Comment: Have you tried it and it doesn't work? Spring Cloud Feign uses the same `HttpMessageConverters` object that Spring MVC uses. Configuring it the normal Spring Boot way should 'just work' (thought I haven't tried it myself). http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: @spencergibb I can override the ObjectMapper and it is correctly used by all Spring MVC controllers and all the Feign clients. However, what I need is a particular feign client, out of the many, to use a different object mapper from the one configured by default. I'm not sure how to even get started to make this work.

Comment: You'd have to create a `SpringDecoder` bean using the doc link a previously posted and mess with it there.

Comment: @spencergibb, I got to work as shown in the answer below. Thanks for you help.

Comment: https://blog.birost.com/a?ID=00600-16a0c674-d3f2-41a7-8e41-335e75f48dd0

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper), you can provide a custom decoder for your Feign client as shown below.

Feign Client Interface:

```
@FeignClient(value = "foo", configuration = FooClientConfig.class)
public interface FooClient{
    //Your mappings
}
```

Feign Client Custom Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class FooClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(customObjectMapper());

        HttpMessageConverters httpMessageConverters = new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter);
        ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> objectFactory = () -> httpMessageConverters;


        return new ResponseEntityDecoder(new SpringDecoder(objectFactory));
    }

    public ObjectMapper customObjectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Customize as much as you want
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: worked for me simply with `return new JacksonDecoder(customObjectMapper());`

Comment: This works very good. Thanks

Comment: @TuGordoBello please consider the updated version of this answer.

Answer (score 14):

follow @NewBie`s answer, i can give the better one...

```
  @Bean
  public Decoder feignDecoder() {
    return new JacksonDecoder();
  }
```

if you want use jackson message converter in feign client, please use JacksonDecoder, because SpringDecoder will increase average latency of feignclient call **in production**.

```
    <!-- feign-jackson decoder -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
      <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>10.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What's the dependency? And version? Can you show the pom.xml entry for this?

Comment: Can you quantify the increase in latency in either percentage or ms or something? I'd like a reference point for how much difference this makes. Looks clean though.

Comment: great improved in my impression, 10ms average improved for 8k qps in production.

Comment: Could you show how you pass a custom ObjectMapper in your solution?

Answer (score 4):

@NewBie's answer has serious performance problems. During the `new HttpMessageConverters` process, loadclass will be performed, resulting in a large number of thread block. If you have used this code, please modify it as follows:

```
ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> objectFactory = () -> new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter);
```

change to

```
HttpMessageConverters httpMessageConverters = new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter);
ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> objectFactory = () -> httpMessageConverters;
```

You can use JMeter and [Arthas](https://arthas.aliyun.com/doc/en/) to reproduce this phenomenon, and the modified program has been greatly improved.

Answer (score 1):

you can use SpringDecoder and SpringEncoder.

```
public SpringDecoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters)
```

is deprecated. you should use another constructor:

```
public SpringDecoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters,
            ObjectProvider<HttpMessageConverterCustomizer> customizers)
```

for example:

```
    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder(ObjectProvider<HttpMessageConverterCustomizer> customizers) {
//        HttpMessageConverter<?> jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(customObjectMapper());
//        HttpMessageConverters httpMessageConverters = new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter);
        
        var httpMessageConverters = new HttpMessageConverters();
        return new ResponseEntityDecoder(new SpringDecoder(() -> httpMessageConverters, customizers));
    }

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        var httpMessageConverters = new HttpMessageConverters();
        return new SpringEncoder(() -> httpMessageConverters);
    }
```

if you want to write a decode time customizer, then you can wright like this:

```
@Component
public class HttpMessageCustomizer implements HttpMessageConverterCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void accept(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters) {
        //customizing
    }

    @Override
    public Consumer<List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>> andThen(Consumer<? super List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>> after) {
        return HttpMessageConverterCustomizer.super.andThen(after);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom decoder as below, annotated with `@Configuration` and set as parameter for the feign client interface, `configuration = CustomFeignClientConfig.class`

```
@Configuration
public class CustomFeignClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        return (response, type) -> {
            String bodyStr = Util.toString(response.body().asReader(Util.UTF_8));
            JavaType javaType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(type);
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue( bodyStr, javaType);
        };
    }
}
```